# Postgres JsonB data deep level searching

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

```
-- PostgreSQL 11.17

CREATE TABLE products(
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
json_data JSONB NOT null
);

insert into products(json_data) values('{"metadata":{"prompts":[{"id":"ITEMS","children":[{"id":"Level1","name":"Dairy","children":[{"id":"Level2","name":"Yogurt","children":[{"id":"Level3","name":"Sweetened","children":[{"id":"Level4","name":"Probiotic"}]}]}]}]}]}}');
insert into products(json_data) values('{"metadata":{"prompts":[{"id":"ITEMS","children":[{"id":"Level1","name":"Dairy","children":[{"id":"Level2","name":"Yogurt","children":[{"id":"Level3","name":"Probiotic","children":[{"id":"Level4","name":"VitaminD"}]}]}]}]}]}}');

select * from products;
```

I would like to get the product id whose item is Probiotic irrespective of any level. Am expecting my query to return product id 1 and 2. But So I come up with the query like this.

```
SELECT id
FROM products,
  JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(json_data->'metadata' -> 'prompts') AS prompts,
  JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(prompts->'children') AS level1,
  JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(level1->'children') AS level2,
  JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(level2->'children') AS level3,
  JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(level3->'children') AS level4
WHERE level3 ->> 'name' = 'Probiotic'
or level4 ->> 'name' = 'Probiotic';
```

In this case, I need to dig into all the levels and find out the name is Probiotic or not. In other words, i need to know the level where the name is Probiotic.

How to come up with the query, where query itself dig into all levels and find out where its Probiotic or not.

I tried something like below and is not returning any result

```
--NOT working
SELECT products.id
FROM products
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT TRUE 
       FROM jsonb_array_elements(json_data->'metadata' -> 'prompts') prompts
       WHERE prompts @> ANY(ARRAY[
           JSONB '{ "name":"Probiotic" }'
              ]
       )
);
```

SQL Fiddle link:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/100580

Thanks.

Comment: Would be quite easy with a current Postgres version that supports JSON path: `json_data @? 'strict $.metadata.prompts[*].** ? (@.name == "Probiotic")'`, but this is not available in Postgres 11 (this was introduced in Postgres 12)

Comment: Not very smart but might do the job: `select id from products where json_data::text ~ "name":"Probiotic";`

Comment: @Stefanov.sm json data will be huge in my case. I feared about the performance if I go with this.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks. I tried your solution with Postgres 15, and it yielded the expected result:<br/>    SELECT id
FROM products
where json_data @? 'strict $.metadata.prompts[*].** ? (@.name == "Probiotic")'; However I dont see indexing happened. I created index like this: <br/>    CREATE INDEX idx_products_json_data ON products USING gin (json_data);